# Django on Google App Engine: debug queries to datastore

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

What is the best way to get something similar to django-debug-toolbar working on Google App Engine? At least I want to log all GQL at my local development environment. I am using django-nonrel + djangoappengine + djangotoolbox.

I tried:

- debug-toolbar - does not work
- http://popcnt.org/2008/05/google-app-engine-tips.html - link to the code is broken
- http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/c9e8a906a88a8102 - a lot of work needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html), which comes with the App Engine Python SDK.